# Form action showing two controller actions in cakephp form

Tags: forms, cakephp, controller, action

I am new to cakephp and currently building a login authentication page. My `users_controller.php` is:

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Users';
    var $components = array('Auth');

    function index() {

    }
    function login() {

    }
    function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout);
    }
}
```

And `login.ctp` is

```
<?php
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
echo $this->Form->create('Users');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end('Login');

?>
```

But when I checked the page source, the action of the form is `<form action="/student/app/webroot/index.php/users/users/login" id="UsersLoginForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">`. As you can see there are two `users` controller in the action . Why this additional `user` is coming ?

NB: Cakephp version `1.3`. All our projects were done in this version and not yest upgraded !

Comment: May be url rewriting problem

Comment: Yeah - sounds like just a server issue - mod_rewrite not on or something.